# present progressive AND present simple

Tags: grammar

If I say "I've got a headache, my head is hurting", does it mean that usually I don't have headache  and if I say ""I've got a headache, my head hurts" does it mean that I have headache very often and that when I have it hurts

Comment: In intent, they are identical, imo. I would prefer the second version, but the first 'doesn't hurt' ;)

Comment: Ditto on the preference for #2. Neither speaks to whether you have headaches often or rarely.  *I get headaches* means you often have them.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, there is little difference; however a native speaker would generally use the second form - although I probably would only use one half of the sentence anyway - in which case any of the 3 would be acceptable. There's little point in specifying that your head hurts, in a headache!

Comment: Exactly  . . but if you (OP) wrote it down in that redundant fashion, as in your examples,  you wouldn't use a comma; you would use a semicolon, a colon, or an em-dash.

Answer (score -1):

Simple present tense talks about habitual actions, general truth and daily activities. /my head hurts/ doesn't mean it usually happens. /my head hurts/ describes what happens now.

/my head is hurting/ is not correct pattern. it seems that your head is doing something to make your head headache. Lol!